# QML scaling does not work with non-integer scaling factors

Tags: windows, qt, user-interface, qml

I'm writing an application using QML. I'm having trouble when I scale my GUI by non-integer factors. [According to the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html), `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` should enable device-independent pixels, therefore automatically taking care of most of the scaling:

> The application attribute `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling`, introduced in
>   Qt 5.6, enables automatic scaling based on the pixel density of the
>   monitor.

In a [blog post about 5.6](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/26/high-dpi-support-in-qt-5-6/), they admit that there can be problems:

> #### Q: Are non-integer scale factors supported?
>
> A: Qt uses qreal in the
>   API, and will allow setting non-integer scale factors via
>   `QT_SCALE_FACTOR`. However, Qt does not guarantee that graphics and
>   styles will be glitch-free in that case. Styles may break first: the
>   fusion style is generally most scalable. The Qt platform plugins round
>   the reported scale factors to the nearest integer.

and in a comment:

> Q: Does that mean it’s still effectively integer-only? What happens to Windows with 150% DPI scale?
>
> A: Yes, unless you set/correct it manually with `QT_SCALE_FACTOR`. 150% should then go to 2x.

So for me this leads to a comically large GUI when scaling to 150%. However, the text scales correctly which leads to weird artifacts such as large button with small text.

Am I misunderstanding how this works or is it just not really possible yet?

Comment: I had some issues with this, too. So now I scale the app manually by passing a command line argument and utilizing `Qt.application.arguments`.

Comment: There seems to be some movement towards a more complete solution: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53022

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, I was not satisfied by `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` so I decided to make it my self, and created a `ScaleableWindow` like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    property real scale: 1
    property real unscaledWidth: 100
    property real unscaledHeight: 100

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var i = Qt.application.arguments.indexOf('--scale')
        if (i > -1 && Qt.application.arguments[i+1]) scale = parseFloat(Qt.application.arguments[i+1])
    }

    width: unscaledWidth * scale
    height: unscaledHeight * scale

    property alias scaledContentItem: scaledContent
    default property alias scaledContent: scaledContent.data

    Item {
        id: scaledContent
        width: root.unscaledWidth
        height: root.unscaledHeight
        scale: root.scale
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

You can now specify the scale-factor by passing e.g. the commandline argument `--scale 0.4`

You can also try to use [`Screen.pixelDensity`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html#pixelDensity-attached-prop) to calculate a scaleing factor, but that relies on the display to correctly publish its pixel density, which failed for me quite often.

You can also use this to create a window that scales the content automatically, when you resize the window.

---

So if the question is *Is it possible with the environment variable* - I don't think so. If the question is *Is it possible to scale the window and its content based on some external input* - here is a solution.

Comment: This looks like an interesting solution, I'm a bit suprised that it should be this easy. Have you also tried `Screen.devicePixelRatio`? Did you keep `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling`?

Comment: No, I don't have any environment variables set anymore.

Comment: `Screen.devicePixelRatio` has a fancy documentation: *1.0 on normal screens and 2.0 on Apple retina displays* - seriously? What is it on a *MS Surface*? What is a normal screen? I did not dare to use that :D

Comment: Do you have a solution for the case where you want to scale the UI based on the DPI setting of the monitor? Currently I would like to enable high-dpi for all integer scaling factors and disable it for everything else, but I don't see a way of doing this.

Comment: (update 2): I was intrigued and went on a journey: `Screen.devicePixelRatio` returns `d->platformScreen->devicePixelRatio() * QHighDpiScaling::factor(this);` where [`devicePixelRatio()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowsscreen.h) is hard-coded as `1.0` on windows. [`QHighDpiScaling`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/kernel/qhighdpiscaling.cpp) is an interesting class with a lot of documentation.

Comment: That stuff should definitely be a singleton rather than a dynamic scope property, considering it is something that will be used all over the place, there is a lot of overhead to be cut by being able to address the properties directly rather than looking them up down the object tree.

Comment: What are the `property alias` and `default property alias` lines and why are width/height bound to unscaledWidth/unscaledHeight instead the other way around to make the resize work?

Comment: `property alias`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655106/qml-property-vs-alias
`default property`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties - Item.data is the default property of an Item (or standard descendants of it). So it is a good choice to select the Item.data of the main content placeholder Item as default property of your custom Item.